# Spark MongoDB connector - Too much time to write in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, scala, apache-spark

I'm using Mongo Spark connector to write about 8 million of documents in a collection (specified in writeConf):

```
MongoSpark.save(dataset, writeConf)
```

Every document is pretty tiny, just two String fields and a Double field. It takes 1 hour to complete the job (most of the time it is in    foreachPartition at MongoSpark.scala:130).

I'm using two M4 amazon machines (4 cores, 16 gb) for Spark so I don't think it's just a hardware problem. Latency between Spark and Mongo is 0.254 ms, really fast.

So, question is, is there any way to parallelize more the task or make it faster?

Comment: How many partitions are there? How many workers are there? What version of the Spark Connector are you using?

Comment: I'm using 8 workers (1 cpu and 3 gb each one). Mongo connector is 2.0.0.  I'm not sure of how many partitions i'm using, so probably is the default value.

Comment: Can you add the DAG analysis of the job from the web interface. That may produce more information as to where the bottle necks are.